# What makes a union member active?

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, c++17, unions

What makes a union member active?

I've read chapter 9.5 of the C++14 standard (the one about unions), but I haven't found a clear answer to what makes a union member active.

There is a note:

> In general, one must use explicit destructor calls and placement new
>   operators to change the active member of a union.

So for example,

```
union U {
  int i;
  short s;
} u;

new(&u.i) int(42);
```

Okay, placement new changes the active member, it's clear. But we usually don't use placement new when working with types with trivial constructors.

Does `operator=` change the active member without UB?

```
u.i = 42;
```

Here, `operator=` called on an unconstructed object. Is it well defined?

What about this?

```
struct A {
  int i0;
  int i1;
};
union U {
  A a;
  short s;
} u;
```

What makes `a` to be the active member of `u`? Is setting both `i0` & `i1` enough?

```
u.a.i0 = 42;
u.a.i1 = 99;
```

What if I write:

```
u.a.i0 = 42;     // supposedly this doesn't change the active member to a, as i1 isn't set
int x = u.a.i0;  // is it fine to read from a.i0? a is not an active member supposedly
```

After `u.a.i0 = 42;`, the active member isn't changed to `a` (I think), so is it UB to do `int x = u.a.i0;`?

Does C++17 improve on the description of active members?

Comment: "Here, `operator=` called on an unconstructed object" are you sure? It's POD so it seems fine.

Comment: Laymen definition is that this is the element last written to. But I can't find any substantiation of this in the standard.

Comment: @BartoszKP: well, it's DynamicType is certainly (?) not `int`, so... I don't know :)

Comment: This is fixed in C++17, which describes the process of switching an active member in greater detail in [**\[class.union\]/5**](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.union#5)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, your comment is actually an answer.

Comment: @SergeyA Well, the question is specifically about C++14. I don't have an answer for that.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: whoops. I didn't expect that they improved on this (usually they focus on high level stuff). I edited my answer, so a C++17 related answer is absolutely OK for me. But even I can now answer my question :)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik this was reworded with [P0137R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0137r1.html) which resolves [DR1116](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1116) which has `CD4` status which I believe means the defect applies to C++14 as well but not 100% on that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C++17, a paragraph was added that explicitly discusses cases like `u.i = 42`:

> **[class.union]/5** When the left operand of an assignment operator involves a member access expression (8.2.5) that nominates a union member, it may begin the lifetime of that union member, as described below. For an expression `E`,
>   define the set `S(E)` of subexpressions of `E` as follows:
>
> (5.1) — If `E` is of the form `A.B`, `S(E)` contains the elements of `S(A)`, and also contains `A.B` if `B` names a union member of a non-class, non-array type, or of a class type with a trivial default constructor that is not deleted, or an array of such types.
>
> (5.2) — If `E` is of the form `A[B]` and is interpreted as a built-in array subscripting operator, `S(E)` is `S(A)` if `A` is of array type, `S(B)` if `B` is of array type, and empty otherwise.
>
> (5.3) — Otherwise, `S(E)` is empty.
>
> In an assignment expression of the form `E1 = E2` that uses either the built-in assignment operator (8.18) or a trivial assignment operator (15.8), for each element `X` of `S(E1)`, if modification of `X` would have undefined behavior under 6.8, an object of the type of `X` is implicitly created in the nominated storage; no initialization is performed and the beginning of its lifetime is sequenced after the value computation of the left and right operands and before the assignment. [ *Note:* This ends the lifetime of the previously-active member of the union, if any (6.8). *—end note* ]

(Followed by a longish example that I'm too lazy to format properly, but which you can see [here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.union#5).)